# xpages theme add script library to a scpecific XPage

Tags: xpages

All my XPages apart from "DefaultLogin.xsp" have a resource of xpServerSide added to them, but wondered if there was a way to add this resource via the theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add resources to your theme like this:

```
<theme extends="whatever">
    <resources>
        <bundle src="prop.properties" var="strings"></bundle> <!-- propertie example -->
        <dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.ExtLib"></dojoModule><!-- dojo module example  -->
        <script src="/whatever.js" clientSide="true"></script><!-- scriptlibray example -->
    </resources>
....
...
</theme>
```

This will add your script, properties or dojoModule to all your XPages if this theme is selected.

You can also extend this by adding a `rendered` attribute to the `<resource>` tag. to load it only on special conditions. e.g.:

```
<resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isFirefox()}">
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>stylesFF.css</href>
</resource>
```